# DNS record with same name for A and NS record types

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, amazon-route53

I am not sure of this but was trying to understand if the two DNS records of the record of 'A' and 'NS' type can have the same in the domain?

like:

```
A.m.b.example NS -> [ NS servers ]

A.m.b.example A -> IP address
```

I am trying to give this a try in my route53 on AWS, apparently `NS` record is resolving but not the IP address. TTL is about 60 for both of them.

Comment: If you've set up `NS` records for `a.m.b.com`, you've delegated that subdomain to those nameservers. Your `A` record needs to be on *those* nameservers - if it's on your `b.com` or `m.b.com` nameservers it'll be ignored.

Comment: yup, but I would like to have an A record of `a.m.b.com` as well that should resolve to an IP. It looks like route53 allows me to create that A record but does not resolve, interestingly it does not allow me to create conflicting CNAME record when NS record already exists, which is understandable.

Comment: You can create the records they way that you describe. However, the A record will be ignored as the NS records say go "to-a-different-dns-server" for name resolution. You then need to create the A.m.b.com on the DNS servers that the NS records point to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> yup, but I would like to have an A record of a.m.b.com as well that should resolve to an IP.

You have delegated control of `a.m.b.example` to the set of nameservers in your new `NS` records. You can certainly have an `A` record for `a.m.b.example`, but you must now create it *in the nameservers listed* in the `NS` record.

Comment: >>but you must now create it in the nameservers listed in the NS record.
Would not that ask for creating device/instance records under `a.m.b.example` instead as in `a.a.m.b.example` ?

Comment: @NikhilMulley No, for the same reasons that the nameservers for `example.com` can have an apex record for `example.com`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag as the right answer. Yes, route53 allows to create an apex A record of the same name as the public domain and it does resolve fine. It just took some time to materialize and propagate the DNS (ttl). Thanks @ceejayoz